# Аналог first_or_create для has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть ли подобные методы для ассоциации has_one? т.е. например две модели `User` и `Profile`. Как сделать создание `profile`, при вызове `@user.profile` (если профиля для этого юзера пока не существует)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Предположим, что есть, попробуем его найти.

Тогда такой метод может быть только у объекта, у которого ассоциация определена, т. к. соответствующий метод возвращает либо сам объект, либо `nil`, в отличие от `has_many`, метод из которого возвращает `CollectionProxy`, в который можно уместить что-то дополнительное.

```
class One < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :thing, # У меня были сходные по названию поля, поэтому я изменил имя ассоциации
          foreign_key: 'one_id',
          class_name: 'Two'
end

class Two < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :one
end


[25] pry(main)> One.first.methods.grep /thing/
=> [:autosave_associated_records_for_thing,
 :thing,
 :thing=,
 :build_thing,
 :create_thing,
 :create_thing!]
```

#### Н-неа, нету.